# Scroll View lightening background color

Tags: swift, xcode, background, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am using the same background on different views in my app and remarked something strange with the only view where I use a `UIScrollView`: the background is lighter than expected.

Uninstalling the `scroll view` gives it its color back. I am 100% positive this comes from the `scroll view` only and not it's subviews because uninstalling anything (and everything) else inside the `scroll view` has no effect.

No `scroll view`:

[image: Background]

Scroll view :

[image]

Is there any solution to fix that?